# Custom Post Type page template doesn't show up

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

I created a custom post type called portfolio.  I also created a file called single-portfolio.php to display the portfolio content.

When creating a portfolio post, the template I want to use doesn't show up in the dropdown list under the Attributes section.  In fact, the dropdown list doesn't show up at all until I create my first portfolio post, at which point, the dropdown list is populated with two items:

-(no parent)

-[Title of the first Portfolio post]

Here's what's in functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'create_portfolio');
function create_portfolio() {
$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('My Portfolio', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Portfolio Item', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'portfolio item'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Portfolio Item'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Portfolio Item'),
    'new_item' => __('New Portfolio Item'),
    'view_item' => __('View Portfolio Item'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Portfolio'),
    'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);
$portfolio_args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'label' => __('Portfolio'),
    'singular_label' => __('Portfolio'),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'rewrite' => array("slug" => "portfolio"),
    'can_export' => true,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'page-attributes')
   );
register_post_type('portfolio',$portfolio_args);
}
```

And single-portfolio.php

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Single Portfolio
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="main">
<?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => 10)); 
?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<?php   
    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $screenshot_url = $custom["screenshot_url"][0];
    $website_url = $custom["website_url"][0];
    $date_completed = $custom["date_completed"][0];
?>
    <div id="portfolio-item">
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php echo 'Completed:'; $custom["year_completed"][0]; ?>
<a href="<?=$website_url?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> </a>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

</div><!--MAIN-->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused as to what Page Attributes will give you access to. To the best of my knowledge you do not get a drop down to choose a template (as you do on Pages) as an automatic function on custom post types.

That being said, you are on the right track. You need to make an archive-portfolio.php file as well to display all of the portfolio posts as well.

You do not need an additional WP_Query to pull in your correct post type - WordPress will do that correctly based on single-POSTTYPE.php.

Ditch that line and revert to the standard loop - and ditch the template name as well. It does not do anything. If you really, really, really want to use this as a Page, rename the template page-portfolio.php and create a page, select this template and you'll be off like a shot.

Comment: You're right.  I was kinda confused.  What I wound up doing was going ahead and creating the file page-portfolio.php and selecting the template.  So far, I'm getting the results I want.  Thanks for your help!